# undefined reference to `ERR_load_crypto_strings'

Tags: linux, makefile, openssl, linker-errors

I am trying to get OpenSSL to work, but it seems to have a problem with linking. Here is what I did:

1. I downloaded OpenSSL for Linux from https://www.openssl.org/source/ I tried versions 0.9.8zc, 1.0.0o and 1.0.1j, all with the same result.
2. I installed each OpenSSL version using ./config, make and sudo make install.
3. For debugging purposes, I went to /usr/lib/ssl and used sudo chmod -R 777 * to remove any restrictions that could have caused the error.
4. I created the following program:

## main.c:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
int main(void) {
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

5. I created the following makefile in the same directory as my .c file:

## makefile:

```
all: main.o
    cc -o main main.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -lcrypto -lssl
main.o: main.c
    cc -c -Wall main.c -I/usr/local/ssl/include/ -o main.o
```

6. When I run the makefile, I get the following error:

cc -o main main.o -L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -lcrypto -lssl
/usr/local/ssl/lib//libssl.a(ssl_err2.o): In function `SSL_load_error_strings':
ssl_err2.c:(.text+0x4): undefined reference to`ERR_load_crypto_strings'
/usr/local/ssl/lib//libssl.a(ssl_err.o): In function `ERR_load_SSL_strings':
ssl_err.c:(.text+0xc): undefined reference to`ERR_func_error_string'
ssl_err.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `ERR_load_strings'
ssl_err.c:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to`ERR_load_strings'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1

What am I doing wrong?

Cheers
Alex

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As answered on the maillist by scott_n but for the record here, swap the order to `-lssl -lcrypto`.

Explanation: for static C libraries in general on nearly all systems, members of library files like `libxxx.a` are only pulled in by the linker if they define things *referenced from translation units already linked* i.e. to the left in the command line. OpenSSL libssl has (numerous) references to libcrypto. If you link -lcrypto first, those references haven't been seen, so the libcrypto files aren't linked; then you link -lssl and create the unsatisfied references. In cases of mutual dependency also called recursive dependency you may need to *repeat* a library like `-lcrypto -lssl -lcrypto` but OpenSSL has no such "backward" references.

Comment: Wow. Now **that's** something I didn't expect to be a possible solution, but it works now. Thanks for adding it here, because I forgot to subscribe to the ML because I thought I'd get answers to my questions regardless and in the archive his answer is encrypted.